# How to rename many files, using a prefix ID?

Tags: command-line, scripts, filemanager

I have 103 directories. These directories are named as `PJA_XXX`, where `XXX` is a number from 71 to 174. Inside each `PJA_XXX` folder I have a file under the next path: `PJA_XXX/results/variants/variants.vcf`.

I want to rename the `variants.vcf` file adding  the prefix of the `PJA_XXX` directory that contains it. So the expected result would be `PJA_XXX_variants.vcf`.

I think I could do it with a shell loop, but I don't know how to take the name of the `PJA_XXX` folder n order to rename the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *loop variable*, and reference it using `${loop_variable_name}` in your command.

Use...

```
for directory_name in PJA_*; do
    echo "Processing ${directory_name}."
    mv "${directory_name}/results/variants/variants.vcf" "${directory_name}/results/variants/${directory_name}_variants.vcf"
done
```

...to modify the file structure like...

```
PJA_001
└── results
    └── variants
        └── variants.vcf
PJA_002
└── results
    └── variants
        └── variants.vcf
PJA_003
└── results
    └── variants
        └── variants.vcf
PJA_004
└── results
    └── variants
        └── variants.vcf
PJA_005
└── results
    └── variants
        └── variants.vcf
```

...into the file structure like this...

```
PJA_001
└── results
    └── variants
        └── PJA_001_variants.vcf
PJA_002
└── results
    └── variants
        └── PJA_002_variants.vcf
PJA_003
└── results
    └── variants
        └── PJA_003_variants.vcf
PJA_004
└── results
    └── variants
        └── PJA_004_variants.vcf
PJA_005
└── results
    └── variants
        └── PJA_005_variants.vcf
```

Comment: Note: The above bash script assumes you do _not_ have spaces in any of your file or directory names. If you do, edit your question to indicate that.

Comment: Nicely written answer. Odd seeing "variant" in filenames at this point in our history.